# C# WebAPI - Returned JSON is wrapped with square brackets

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have basic API that returns Building data.

```
 public IList<Buildings> GetByBuildingId(int building_id)
    {
        return _context.building.ToList();
    }
```

Why is my returned JSON being wrapped in square brackets and being interpreted as an array instead on Building object?

```
**[**
    {
        "Attributes": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": {
```

Therefore when I try and deserialize I get the Error:

```
Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) to deserialize correctly
```

What is wrong?  thx!

Comment: The call returns an `IList<Buildings>` - a list/collection is represented in JSON as an **array** (which is what those "square brackets" really are). So from where I stand, this is **just fine and correct** - your call will **NOT** return a single `Building` instance - but potentially multiple `Buildings` entries - therefore the resulting JSON will be an array - works as designed....So you need to deserialize to a **list** or **collection** of buildings - not just a single one

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the return type of your method to a return a single object. 
Then you update the `_context.building.ToList();` to use your `building_id` to a where clause